# Find Variable Value + Symbol Combination

Tags: vba, excel, find, symbols

I have the following problem. I am reading unsorted text from a pdf into excel, filling my worksheet with rather random entries.

No I am searching for elements which works quite well for most parts, I am just running into major problems finding a variable value & symbol & variable value combination.
The combinations like e.g. `0/700` occur in different parts and show no order in which to find them.

Example Table:

```
100 mt/h 
m³/t
S/C
0/700
0/25
5/31
43/47
700/1000
```

I need to find everything that is a "number"/"number" combination e.g. `0/700`. Problem is the only constant in that is the "/" (slash), which occurs also in other cells. So I am wondering if there is a chance to search for number / number.

I tried the following:

```
Set prdct = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1:K100").Find("/")
```

Giving me all entries that have a slash occuring which unfortunately doesnt help. 
So I went a bit further by trying:

```
Set prdct = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1:K100").Find("\d*/\d*")
Set prdct = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1:K100").Find("\d*"&"/"&"\d*")
Set prdct = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1:K100").Find("\d+/\d+")
Set prdct = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1:K100").Find("\d+"&"/"&"\d+")
```

All the last ones return `Nothing`, so obviously something isn't working out. 
If it helps the maximum value on the left side of the slash can be max `999`, on the right side of the slash maximum `9999`. But it can be `0/1` as well. 
I would really appreciate any help, hints different appraoches and the like. Cheers.

Comment: so you want to find an `integer/integer` ... try googling on those lines. May push you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The only idea I get from that is finding all "/" entries and then loop and check if the value before and after isnumeric, or is there a smarter way that I am not seeing? (Not sure this will work, but I'll try)

Comment: I am not a vba expert but I think you have to create a regex object `Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")` then define `regex.pattern ="\d+/\d+"` then execute `matches = regex.execute(Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1:K100")` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, check it out:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim arrInput    As Variant
    Dim varVar      As Variant
    Dim lngCounter  As Long

    arrInput = [{"100 mt/h","m3/t","S/C","0/700","0/25","5/31","43/47","700/1000"}]

    For Each varVar In arrInput
        Debug.Print varVar
        Debug.Print blnCheck2Integers(varVar)
        Debug.Print "------------------------------"
    Next varVar

End Sub

Public Function blnCheck2Integers(ByVal strInput As String, _
                                            Optional strDelim = "/") As Boolean

    Dim arrTemp As Variant

    arrTemp = Split(strInput, strDelim)
    If UBound(arrTemp) <> 1 Then Exit Function
    blnCheck2Integers = IsNumeric(arrTemp(0)) And IsNumeric(arrTemp(1))

End Function
```

You split by "/" and then check whether the two values are numeric or not. If the values are not 2, you return false. This is the result in the console:

```
100 mt/h
False
------------------------------
m3/t
False
------------------------------
S/C
False
------------------------------
0/700
True
------------------------------
0/25
True
------------------------------
5/31
True
------------------------------
43/47
True
------------------------------
700/1000
True
------------------------------
```

Comment: I will try it in a second, will it have an effect if some entries do not contain a "/"?  Thanks a lot anyway already:)

Comment: @KiW - there is a boolean function `blnCheck2Integers`, which is the reason why it works.

Comment: Awesome it works! Really grateful, I was hanging there for a while.

Comment: @KiW - thumbs up! :)